# Java update fails every time

Tags: macos, software-update, java

Every time I install Java updates, I get the following error after the download completes:

> **Update Error!**
>
> An error occurred while downloading the update. Please try again later.

How can I fix this? Things I've already tried:

- Installing the update from the website. The error just comes back with the next update and I do not want to install all of these manually.
- Running `sudo /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Resources/Java Updater.app/Contents/MacOS/Java Updater` on the command line.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: What is the URL you used on the website?

Comment: It has been a while since I did the manual install, but if my browser's internet history is accurate I used http://java.com/en/download/mac_download.jsp.

Comment: That is the JRE I suspect you want the JDK

Comment: Why should I get the Development Kit when I only want to run - not develop - Java software?

Comment: Because Oracle messed it up

Comment: Same problem here.